# Switch from Milia to Apartment - keep data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

We have a product that has been built using the `milia` multi-tenanting gem (https://github.com/jekuno/milia) . Unfortunately it seems this gem is dead. We can't upgrade past Rails 5 because of this.

Is there any way to move from milia to another gem (eg `apartment` https://github.com/influitive/apartment - though I see that hasn't been updated in 2 years either!) and not force everyone to recreate passwords etc?

Comment: I've skimmed through the milia repo and it seems like they rely on https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant which is a conceptually different approach from apartment. Apartment uses schemas/dbs to separate tenants while acts_as_tenant uses tenant_id column, so migrating to apartment would be more troublesome than just resetting users passwords. Apartment has been more or less maintained under https://github.com/rails-on-services/apartment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying Milia to work with Rails 6.
That new gem is called [Philia](https://github.com/philsmy/philia)

Comment: I see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue trying gem milia had to use acts_as_tenant- which is well upto date  and supports rails 5.2 upwards and its syntax close to gem 'acts_as_tenant'
https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant